# redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address

Tags: python, docker, redis

Any ideas why I get a connection error when trying to run a redis command from one container to another?
I'm trying to run an old python 2.7 lambda locally in order to test before upgrading to 3.8.10
I'm running a script that builds and links redisdb container with my_app container:

```
docker build . -t my_app:latest
docker pull redis:3.2.4-alpine && \
docker run --name=redisdb -d  redis:3.2.4-alpine redis-server
docker run \
    --rm -t -i -d \
    --link redisdb:redis \
    -h redis -p 6379 \
    -e CONFIG_FILE=local_config.yaml \
    my_app
```

I am running a python script on my_app with the following commands:

```
r = redis.Redis()
r.mset({"Bahamas": "Nassau"})
print(r.get("Bahamas"))
```

I've also tried the top suggestion here: [Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965291/error-99-connecting-to-localhost6379-cannot-assign-requested-address) and passed `r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, decode_responses=True)` with the same results.

Every time I try to run that python script in the my_app container, I get:

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address.
```

When I run the containers and then check `docker ps` I get this:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
76aea9308821   mar-atlas-readings-processor   "python2"                About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:64098->6379/tcp   mar-atlas-readings-processor
f313113341de   redis:3.2.4-alpine             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   6379/tcp                  redisdb
```

This shows the correct port connections.

Comment: first check if you container is running or not?
sudo docker ps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your python app is trying to talk to Redis on localhost but the Redis container is on a different localhost.

You should be able to use the link configured in the `docker run ...` command, i.e `redisdb`, for the `host` option.

Comment: Wow, that resolved it. Thank you kind stranger!