# docker+flask+gunicorn+redis OSError

Tags: python, docker, redis

I have had a very strange problem when I build my docker service. My service framework is docker+gunicorn+flask+redis+vue,I can build the image and up service normally, but when I login it, the error as follows come out.

```
**dw-backend-v2 | 2023-01-12 11:04:30,546 exception_handler.py [line: 28] ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
dw-backend-v2 |   File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 611, in connect
dw-backend-v2 |     sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(
dw-backend-v2 |   File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry
dw-backend-v2 |     return do()
dw-backend-v2 |   File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 612, in <lambda>
dw-backend-v2 |     lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)
dw-backend-v2 |   File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 677, in _connect
dw-backend-v2 |     raise err
dw-backend-v2 |   File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 665, in _connect
dw-backend-v2 |     sock.connect(socket_address)
dw-backend-v2 | OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address**
```

docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  backend:
    build:
        context: ./dw_backend
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: dw-backend:2.0.0
    container_name: dw-backend-v2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9797:9797"
    volumes:
      - "./dw_backend:/home/data_warehouse/app"
    # privileged: true
    environment:
      TZ: "Asia/Shanghai"
      FLASK_ENV: DEBUG
      RD_HOST: redis
      RD_PORT: 6379
      RD_DB: 2
      RD_PWD:
      RD_POOL_SIZE: 10
      RD_KEY_EXPIRE: 43200

  frontend:
    hostname: dw-frontend-v2
    container_name: dw-frontend-v2
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./dw_frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8150:80" 
      - "2443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./dw_frontend/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html
    links:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - backend
    environment:
      TZ: "Asia/Shanghai"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: common_net
```

I even deleted all the codes related to redis, but the same error still happened! I could't find any solutions to solve this problem.

And my another one service is normal,all of the services connected same redis service, the difference between service I and service II is service II is restful API but service I is not.
Does anyone know the reason for this problem?

There are also no any ports keep in "TIME_WAIT" status!

I have tried to delete all the code related to redis and even write a new method to connect redis, but no miracle has happened!

I hope someone can help me solve it.

Comment: 1) There are several libraries which integrate redis into Django. Which one are you using? 2) What is the hostname which you are connecting to? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68318473/redis-exceptions-connectionerror-error-99-connecting-to-localhost6379-cannot) says this problem can be caused by connecting to localhost is Redis is running at a different hostname.

Comment: @NickODell I used flask-redis-ext library, and my redis service build as docker container, name is redis, all the service in same network "common_net", so, I connected the redis in the docker container name "redis" as my docker-compose. But the serious problem is when I removed all the codes about redis, the same error still raised.

Comment: redis service run as:  docker run --restart=always --net=common_net -p 6379:6379 --name redis -v /mnt/md0/redis/conf/redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf -v /mnt/md0/redis/data:/data -d redis redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf

Answer (score -1):

OK，I solved this problem，I add a parameter "extra_hosts: localhost: redis" in my docker-compose.yml file, it's solved !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).